# Check if json property is null

Tags: javascript, json, xpath, wso2

I have the following input

```
{
  "headers": {
   ...
},
  "body": {
    "RequestInfo": {
     ...
    ,
     "Identificator": null
        }
}

<filter regex="false" source="boolean($ctx:Identificator)"> -check if exist(when it's null it still viewed as existing.)
```

I am creating service in which I check the Identificator value.

But in this case it's null. Can someone give me an example in xpath of how I should make the check since it's null and not a valid value?

EDIT:
Can someone show me in JavaScript how would I get the identificator's value, since that approach doesn't work?

EDIT2: The JS works, but it turns out that in WSO2 when we get the identificator, null is considered as a string so ctx:Identificator='null' works also.

Comment: use regex to check if that property string exists... if not then its null.. hence invalid? I mean I would not even use xpath stuff.. just create a model and deserialise it then do some fluent validation. xpath is part of xml hell.

Comment: That's what I have done...<filter regex="false" source="boolean($ctx:Identificator)">  but as I said it's still recognized as valid value

Comment: oh sorry so the JSON is ` "Identificator": null` ? Then you should be able to use whatever that syntaxy thing you are using to check for `null` probably text check?? donno - because it cant convert null to boolean. its invalid

Comment: Thank you, tried that but still a no go.

Comment: sorry not really sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript you can do that:

```js
    let myJsonString = "{
       "headers": {
            ...
        },
       "body": {
           "RequestInfo": {
                ...,
               "Identificator": null
            }
        }
    }"
    const parsedJsonValue = JSON.parse(myJsonString);
    const {body} = parsedJsonValue;
    if(body && body.RequestInfo) {
        const {Identificator} = body.RequestInfo;
        if(Identificator === null || Identificator === undefined) {
            // Identificator is null
        }
    }
```

Hope that this is what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you. Worked.